# Review queues drop down list - review types are ordered by what logic?

Tags: support, review-queues, top-bar

The **Review queues** option is now extended with drop down list, the new approach is awesome.

In the [Review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) the review types are ordered by descending of its count.

Looks like the drop down list is not in any order, so the question is on what basis the review types are ordered?

[image: Review]

Comment: Sweet! FR: Sort the dropdown on count.

Comment: Ah, so that's why my usual tactic of mouse-2 on the button (to open in new tab) took me still to the question page again!  Can that be fixed?

Comment: @TobySpeight Hope mouse-2 click on the each review type is opening in a new tab. Not on the main icon.

Comment: @Arulkumar, yes that works - but it requires that you realise you have to mouse-1 click it first!

Comment: @TobySpeight : The [same request is reported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346621/2451726) and solved

Comment: @TobySpeight,  Opening a drop-down is a better UX. It was the only icon of that type which was a direct link instead of opening a drop-down. Having it *not* open a drop-down was a confusing UX. Now, all of the monochrome icons open drop-downs. You just have to unlearn that the icon did something different.

Comment: Shouldn’t it have a grey header with title though? Other icons do have one.

Comment: Recent cross-site dupe on MSE, just to keep things linked: [Review queue item order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296683/230261)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They're ordered *first* by the minimum reputation needed to access the queue, and *then* alphabetically by the name of the queue.

The purpose of this ordering is to keep the list as consistent as possible *until your privilege-level changes* - the hope is that folks use this as their primary means of accessing the queues, and as such we're not forcing reviewers to override their muscle-memory every time they go to access a specific queue - a worthy design goal for a menu that appears on just about every page of the site.