# Link review menu item to review overview

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, top-bar

With the new dropdown in the topbar for the review, I can no longer scrollwheel-click on the menu item to open the review overview page in a new tab. Now I have to open the dropdown and and choose "All Queues" to get there.

At the moment the icon itself just links to `#`, i.e. the current page itself with an empty anchor.

Can this be changed?

Basically I want it to behave the same as the site switcher that links to stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, makes sense.

Bringing the link back.

With you in the next build.