# Review-ban duration not showing anymore?

Tags: discussion, support, review-suspension

I've been banned from reviewing for several days now.

In the last few days, clicking the review button (highlighted for some reason), doesn't show the previous page, which mentioned "Come back in XX days", but only shows the following message:

[image]

Is this an intentional change?
If so, how can I know how many days are left for my ban to be lifted?

Comment: Having found myself in this situation; where the ban was invoked hours after I made the assessment on the post;  I find this a shockingly bad way to feedback to users. SO should be way better than this, and usually is, time to clean-up the attitude of the review-banner bot!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To see when your ban will be lifted visit the [Review Overview](https://stackoverflow.com/review) page which will give you the message you are after. You should also be able to [scrollwheel-click](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346621/link-review-menu-item-to-review-overview) the menu to open the Review Overview page in a new tab.

As for the window showing the message. It would make sense to show the ban message or something similar.

Comment: I was looking for that link for almost a week. Now i finally know how long I am banned :) Thanks you.

Comment: Most importantly, that age also gives the reason for the block. Just blocking people seems a great way of sending them packing.

Comment: I just reviewed a question `Requires editing` which was very helpful as the person who asked question can edit the question to more information. But SO still banned me for 2 days.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil exactly, and when I post an answer about it to the *related* question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293479/there-are-no-review-queues-available-to-you-hey/330491?noredirect=1#comment1078124_330491, I immediately get downvoted.