# Top-bar review drop down can be much quicker

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, top-bar, user-experience

On the new top-bar, the review icon's drop-down list is a nice touch, but it takes too long to load - to me it can take over 2 seconds:

[image: Firefox's timings - 2036ms for review queues]

Compare to the inbox, at 162ms:

[image: Firefox's timings - 162ms for inbox]

I'm guessing it is slow mainly because of the queue size counts.
**Suggestion:** The drop-down can be static and open immediately without the queue sizes visible. Once the drop-down is visible, the queue sizes can be loaded from server.
This will allow clicking on a queues faster.

---

Update: The new review drop down looks awesome, still slow sometimes. Currently I *consistently* get about 1300ms:

[image]
[image]

(The feature is being A/B tested, so I'm guessing the query is still the same)

Related: [Review queues drop down list - review types are ordered by what logic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346610/7586)

Comment: the time taken is to get the current count of items in each queue from server

Comment: @SagarV - Right, that's what I thought too, but the menu can be visible before the count is retrieved.

Comment: It's pointless in my view. I'd prefer readability before running dots. I don't personally need to know there's 1 pending review item and when I visit the queue, it's empty. I'd say these numbers are changing so often that I would simply remove them. Right now I've tried to open queue claiming there's 13 items and the queue is empty.

Comment: Either way you have to wait.

Comment: Maybe the loading can be made even faster by first loading everything except the close vote count, and loading the close vote count with another request. My guess is that the close vote count takes the longest to load. In this scenario the user clicks on the drop-down-icon, the overlay becomes visible, 200ms later all counts except the close vote count are visible, 1500ms later even the close vote count is visible. But maybe there's an even better solution and the database lookups can be sped up significantly.

Comment: There's no need for exact numbers. Colors would be more efficient. The value of the number of items in each queue can be queried every **x** seconds and cached. Then a few rules to render each queue in a different color based on how many review items are present in it. For **example** < 10 would be green. 11 - 50 would be yellow. 51 - 99 would be orange and > 100 would be red. (bonus: 300+ would be flashing red /s) The different colors would convey a sense of urgency for  queues which have a lot of items pending. Not 100% accurate but then again, 100% accuracy is not needed here.

Comment: @Kobi see my update below, looks like they removed the numbers.

Comment: This still happening? I'm not seeing nearly that much of a delay, though it's entirely possible this is user-specific: the vast bulk of the time involved in loading that drop-down is spent in SQL Server figuring out what the outstanding count is *for you* in each queue. If you're still seeing this, I can dig into it a bit.

Comment: @Shog9 - At the moment the menu opens in about 200ms, which is pretty quick. But *sometimes* it is consistently slow: refreshing the page and loading the menu again would still be ~1300ms (I noticed it again 4 days ago). Not sure how to approach that. I'll try to review a little and see if it affects the speed for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure we even need the number, as certain queues will generally always have items in the queue:

[image]

What benefit do we have by seeing those numbers? Other queues that become empty from time to time, there's more value in knowing there's something in the queue.

To me, it could just have 2 states:

- Queue - has items
- Queue - is empty

Generating that boolean state should be far more efficient than actually getting the numbers.

---

**Edit:** found this similar request:

[Review cache indicator / timer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276031/review-cache-indicator-timer)

---

**UPDATE 15 September 2017**

Looks like this request / and below suggestion is going through some testing as I don't see numbers anymore:

[image]

But others including ([@CodyGray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray)) do:

[image]

Comment: As I understand it, there's very little caching, as the numbers are specific to the user (unlike similar topbar indicators elsewhere on SE, which are globally cached).

Comment: There are users though that enjoy the gamification aspect of the site and employ that as motivation to review. If someone wanted to earn a specific badge from reviews they can see a queue has enough reviews in there before they start. Also without the numbers I don't believe there would be the focus that there is on close votes such as the SOCVR team and some queues would just spiral out of control.

Comment: Even empty/not empty states are not guaranteed. You would need to have some locking mechanism implemented. There can be just 1 item to review and before you visit the queue, it can get reviewed. Or the queue can be empty when you popup the menu and in the meantime, some item can get enqueued. So even claiming there is or there is nothing in a queue can be wrong.

Comment: @Victoria but that's no different to the current implementation?!

Comment: What you'll see may not be what you get unless the queues would get locked when you popup that menu (which is of course nonsense). It will always be surprise if there's something inside.

Comment: I agree, the numbers are unnecessary. Just do "Close Votes: `∞`".

Comment: Stackoverflow's queues generally have something in them most of the time; but some of the smaller SE's have volumes low enough that if you've done all the reviews available to you there often won't be anything else immediately available.  (I know the new bar's not global yet, but am assuming it will be at some point in the future.)

Comment: "as certain queues will generally always have items in the queue" [\[citation needed\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353665/792066)

Comment: @CodyGray seems like this suggestion has been implemented, not sure how to confirm as this could potentially be marked as [status-complete]?

Comment: Uhh, well, [I still see numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUw2d.png). It looks like the A/B test has been completed and the red dot has been declared the winner, but the numbers haven't gone away. It loads very quickly for me, though.

Comment: @CodyGray ah ok, will update accordingly.

Comment: Are you seeing something different?

Comment: @CodyGray see my post update, no numbers on my screen.

Comment: @CodyGray I see the red dot popup from time to time too, but still no numbers for me.