# Top bar "review needed red dot" showing, but no red dot in review queues

Tags: bug, top-bar

After clicking on the review icon on the top bar when the red dot is showing, there is sometimes no red dot for any of the review queues. This happens frequently.

[image]

I suspect that this could be because I finished my daily low-quality and suggested-edit review quota, but these are in need of reviewers still. In that case,  the solution would be to disable the red dot on the top bar for users who can't do more of those reviews today.

```
some_red_dot = false

for all review queues
  if need of review AND user can review
    some_red_dot = true
    light red dot for review queue

if some_red_dot is true
  light red dot for top bar
```

Comment: loosely related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353903/ think it's still in a testing phase

Comment: Think that is how it currently works. I know on other sites where I have access to all the review queues I will see a review indicator show when there is nothing that I can review.

Comment: @Tanner test is already over. remember a chat message but can't recall in which room it is added

Comment: @i-- not sure it is completely over as I still see no numbers in my list. Where as the OP has posted an image with numbers on the queues.

Comment: I get the red dot with no red dots on the review queues even without having done any reviews, so your theory doesn't work. My theory is that it appears at random to annoy me into not doing any reviews, or at least that is the result.

Comment: You can't really dismiss this as "slow loading" or caching etc. Because at the point where the site decides to light the red dot in the top bar, it should display the results that lead to that conclusion and nothing else. Alternatively, if I click on the review button after seeing the red dot, and there are no more urgent reviews, the red dot should go away.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It may of course be that this is just a "buggy bug" and there's no rationale behind it :) Regardless, it _is_ a bug.

Comment: The developers are toying with us, luring us into the queue with the red dot, then turning the laser pointer off. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: The `while(true)` that is necessary around this code to make the dot accurate is missing.  The olden number did not count down either so nothing simple to do.

Comment: Very annoying to see a red dot in top bar, but no red dot in a specific queue. I'm going crazy.

Comment: Just faced a similar problem. There was 1 task to be reviewd in all queue's combined (At least those that are available to me [ FP, LA, Triage]).

Comment: FWIW: On other sites the opposite sometimes occurs, no red dot on the top bar but red dots (and grey dots) in the pull down and a count of reviews available greater than zero on the [review queues page](https://stackoverflow.com/review). The reason is because you have skipped and no one else has handled the review, the *notification* (and > 0) remains because the *per user info* isn't accessed until you enter a particular queue and the system tries issuing your job.

Comment: I think the appeance of red dot should be bounded to two modes ON&OFF, and it should disappear as long as OFF mode persists for someone's page.

Answer (score 10):

In your screenshot, my money's on the Reopen queue being the culprit: the "danger zone" for that queue is currently 150+ tasks.

It's really, really easy for a couple of tasks to be completed in the time between you loading a page (red dot appears) and you clicking the button to retrieve the drop-down. Don't believe me? Next time you see this, click the "all queues" link at the top and hover over the images of the last few people to review - you'll get a last activity time displayed, like this:

[image: active 55 secs ago]

Heck, if you keep the page open for a bit you might even see new reviewers pop up in real time, thus illustrating how quickly some of these queues can move (particularly when the red dot appears).

A proper fix for this would probably involve learning from [some old HVAC tech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang%E2%80%93bang_control): adding hysteresis such that, for a given queue, the indicator lights when the setpoint is exceeded or *was recently* exceeded.

Comment: So trigger the red dot on 150, but take it back on 125? Elegant!

Comment: This doesn't explain the bug, see the comment I made above: "You can't really dismiss this as "slow loading" or caching etc. Because at the point where the site decides to light the red dot in the top bar, it should display the results that lead to that conclusion and nothing else. Alternatively, if I click on the review button after seeing the red dot, and there are no more urgent reviews, the red dot should go away."  Then of course at the point where I click review, it might not be urgent any longer.

Comment: New bug today: _no red dot in top bar_ but red dot inside the menu at suggested edits. There were 32 suggested edit reviews, red dot limit supposedly 90. These red dots are just way too glitchy! And when more people notice how buggy and unreliable they are, they will naturally start ignoring the red dot completely. So while you may experience some increase in reviews right new, I think this system will lead to a decrease in the long term. Here's an idea: rollback to the system we had before top bar changes, because it actually worked.

Comment: I've been listening to folks telling me, angrily, that it didn't work for - oh - 5 years now, @Lundin. I don't know why you'd have seen this light up at 32 tasks, but if you see it again please grab a screenshot (and timestamp if possible). That said, I'm coming around to the notion that putting numbers in the dropdown at all is a bad idea: they're expensive to calculate, can never be accurate past the instant they're retrieved, and don't necessarily mean what folks think they do anyway.

Comment: Happened again just now when I loaded main site, clicked on review. [Screenshot](https://screenshots.firefoxusercontent.com/images/bfa07c43-cdac-4791-94d1-2b0307b0d751.png). Time was 9:56 GMT 2017-09-28. The bug is easy to repeat - it persists.

Comment: Btw I clicked on suggested edit, did 1 single review, reloaded site. The counter was accurately reduced by 1 review. Red dot remaining. So no blaming caching.

Comment: + for using the word hysteresis, recently it feels more like [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation).

Answer (score 4):

I thought it was supposed to be solved by now, but it seems like it's still showing red dot when no available queue is red.

[image: Red dot showing with no red dot queue]

Reminders of the supposed 2 conditions to show the red dot :

1. At least one of your available queue is red.

   AND
2. It's been an hour since the review icon has been clicked

This is not what I saw today.

**EDIT** : 2017-12-22

Seem to be solved for me, no red dot showing today.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the Close Votes queue is often in danger, but it's not visible to people with less than 3000 reputation. We're working on fixing that problem so that you only see the indicator if there's a queue with tasks in your privilege level. (For reference: [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly))

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's another queue that I haven't unlocked, it seems the red dot works independent of the review queues.

In the below images, on the left, there is no red dot even though every queue (except Close votes) is red. On the right, the red dot appears (even though the individual queue colors are the same as on the left). When we look at the number of posts in each queue that needs edits, they are almost the same. If there's a cut off point where the red dot is being triggered, it must be somewhere in this region.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: first case] | [image: second case] |
| - Close - 5,432 need review - Reopen - 625 - Low quality answers - 313 - Suggested edits - 376 - First answers - 3,942 - First questions - 5,273 - Late answers - 3,474 - Triage - 500 | - Close - 4,302 need review - Reopen - 623 - Low quality answers - 317 - Suggested edits - 384 - First answers - 3,951 - First questions - 5,305 - Late answers - 3,477 - Triage - 500 |

Comment: So the review-needed indicator on the top bar isn't based exclusively on the threshold it's based on how long it's been since _you_ have looked at the review status. Specifically the indicator appears under the condtions: "1. if any review queue has a red dot (explained below) and 2. if it’s __been at least an hour since you clicked on the review icon__." (emphasis added) from the [initial announcement on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/1099857). Given that at least one SO queue is always in the red, this dot appears every time you don't click the button for an hour.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address this question which is about the review-needed indicator appearing when there are no queues with red dots (as shown in the screenshot in the question all queues are grey). Your screenshots show quite clearly that there are several queues which are in the red. The indicator _should_ appear given the specified conditions.