# Top bar “review needed red dot” showing, but there is nothing to review

Tags: support, review-queues, top-bar

I answered a couple of review questions wrong yesterday. So I am assuming that I have been banned for review for a few days. The red dot keeps been popping up asking me to review but there is nothing for me to review.

[image: The review icon has a red dot. The drop down "Review Queues" just shows a message stating "There are no review queues available to you."]

Comment: does it show a ban message when you go to reviews page?

Comment: loosely related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356697/top-bar-review-needed-red-dot-showing-but-no-red-dot-in-review-queues, not gonna dupe vote in case it is ban related.

Comment: @suraj where is the reviews page now?   I think its defiantly ban related Sure one of the head guys can verify that i miss failed review twice yesterday.   (I maintain at least one of them was link only and should have been closed.).   I cant even find link to tools to check that page because its gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were banned from reviewing by the system, automatically, for making too many incorrect reviews. You should have seen the following message:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17381771.

Because this was the first time you'd been banned in a little over a year, the ban was very short—only 2 days. In fact, it was so short that you've almost missed it! The ban will clear itself in 2 hours.

The real bug here is that [it is not sufficiently obvious from the drop-down that you've been banned from reviewing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351386/make-it-more-obvious-that-youre-review-banned), and that needs to be fixed.

If you're fast, and you look within the next 2 hours, either by navigating directly to https://stackoverflow.com/review or by right-clicking on the review icon in the topbar and opening it in a new tab, you will see the ban message I quoted above.

Comment: I try to behave myself when reviewing.   That one was a miss click on my behalf.  Its only two days so no big deal.   Btw i cant find any link on the top bar to https://stackoverflow.com/review so there was no way for me to know i had been banned.  Might want to add that to the bug list.

Comment: The review icon *itself* is a link, @DaImTo. I'm sure that wasn't your only mistake; you aren't banned for a single mistake. But I'm too busy to look through your review history and find the others. You should be able to do it yourself.

Comment: Nope clicking on the review icon doesn't open a link it just pops open a drop down.   There was two, the other was link only.

Comment: "right-clicking on the review icon in the topbar and opening it in a new tab". Depending on your system configuration, you might also be able to do this in a single motion by middle-clicking.

Comment: Right click open in new tab works.