# Review's red dot in topbar is shown, but the queue that is in danger is grayed out for me

Tags: bug, review-queues, top-bar

Today my topbar showed a red dot, showing that there is a queue "in danger". I opened the queue, and I saw that the suggested edits was >100. Which IMHO is the likely culprit. All other queues that are available to me were in acceptable ranges (10-50).

So far nothing out of the ordinary, although for me the suggested edits was grayed out, since I already took care of 40 reviews today. In this case showing the red dot makes no sense, as I can't take any action on it.

The problems with the red dot have been fairly common, but I believed most was resolved back in December of 2017, as for example per: *[Top bar "review needed red dot" showing, but no red dot in review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356697/top-bar-review-needed-red-dot-showing-but-no-red-dot-in-review-queues)*

**EDIT:**
I just got the chance to get a somewhat illustrative screenshot. The top bar was red before I clicked on it, my queues looked like this:

[image]

Also my history in Suggested edits looks like this:

[image]

**Evidence met by Tiw:**
Just met the *finished but still show* one again, captured screens:

1. Red Dot at topbar while no red below, UTC TIME 16:32 (Feb 4th):
   [image: Red Dot at topbar while no red below]
2. Here I hit *F5* too quick, missed to capture the one has 100 suggest edits, but I saw the number went down:
   [image: Hit F5 times, suggest edits went down]
3. From the number and avatars change, you can see it's not because of *Low quality posts*.
   [image: It's not low quality]

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I just have to blame caching...

Comment: @Tiw, I don't see any avatar changes between your second and third image.

Comment: The red dot even appears if you're banned from reviews, it appears it shows no matter how little access to the review queue you have

Comment: @NickA, I would see that as an acceptable edge-case. Where dev time doesn't warrant the outcome. Since when you get review-banned you most likely ruined it for yourself. But it would be better if it weren't the case.

Comment: @Luuklag  Exactly, the number below has minor change, but the the avatars remain the same, so that means the the lower quality posts are relatively stable by the time.  What I meant is that the number changed very little, and the avatars didn't change at all.

Comment: @NickA  Yeah I met that situation too.

Comment: @Luuklag I don't know how to phrase it better and I want it be concise, so I wrote like that (Non native English speaker). When I met it, apart from *F5*, I also hit *Ctrl + F5* to refresh, so I think it's not about caching.

Comment: @Luuklag  Mistakes do happen sometimes, please don't judge us. In my case, both the two of us reviewers missed a tiny non-intentional grammar error and accepted the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22066690), which was from Jan 30 but rejected by a moderator 2 days ago, the error was the deletion of the word `returns`.

Comment: @Tiw if your English proficiency is inadequate please be aware of that and refrain from reviewing edits that involve mostly grammar. That is why there is a Skip button. Seeing the edit you link it is fairly obvious that the word Returns is essential to the sentence. If you are unable to distinguish these sort of things then frankly you shouldn't be making such reviews.

Comment: @Luuklag I do skip a lot, if you check my reviewing log you can see it. And in that case it's a mistake. I'm not quite good at it, but I think it's enough to get by in most situations, I had IELTS reading 8 score :)

Comment: Today I met this three times, last one at UTC TIME 15:58.

Comment: UTC TIME 2019/3/7 18:37, happens again. -- All reviews finished, but dot showed.