# The First Post review queue indicator seems to be broken (again)

Tags: bug, review-queues

I've noticed today that the First Post review queue indicator has been stuck saying it has high volume - the other queues are updating just fine. Caching issue?

[image: img1]

This isn't the [first time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358151/is-there-an-issue-with-the-review-queue-indicator-today) that we've had an issue with the First Post review queue indicator. Could something else be wrong with it?

This is on Google Chrome.

Comment: Can confirm on chrome Version 72.0.3626.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Confirmed on Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Hey, can anyone repro this on Chrome?

Comment: It seems to be working properly now @CodyGray

Comment: Agreed, looks fixed now.

Comment: @CodyGray as of ~3 hours ago (when this was asked), I could reproduce this on chrome. It seems to be fixed now.

Comment: This is not all that is wrong with the red dots: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373788/reviews-red-dot-in-topbar-is-shown-but-the-queue-that-is-in-danger-is-grayed-o

Comment: @CodyGray can anyone reproduce this on Google Chrome? :p

Comment: I'm seeing this issue with Suggested Edits on Chrome 73.

Comment: can reproduce on mozila for now. Earlier before 4 hours this seemed like fixed. Now its again showing the red dot while the queue is totally empty. @YvetteColomb

Comment: I'm also seeing this, for both first posts and suggested edits. It also seems that rep is not synced to meta (I know it takes a while but it has been half a day now). So, seems like a general cache issue.

Comment: Its also happening with Triage too, using Firefox 66.

Comment: Did a dev change the thousand seperator of the threshold into a decimal seperator perhaps?

Comment: @YvetteColomb can anyone repro this on Chrome?

Comment: Some weird stalls in various places over the past 24 hours, pretty sure they're fixed now - is anyone still seeing this (in... Chrome or anything else...)?

Comment: I reckon this was a plot to get us all doing reviews - because it certainly worked! All queues apart from the close and reopen ones were emptied... crafty.

Comment: @Shog9 does seeing it in pyjamas count?

Answer (score 6):

Its not just the first post queue, but also Triage and Suggested edits.

Not reproed on Chrome but on FF 65.0.1 (64bit) using macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the actual response:

```
<div class="topbar-dialog review-dialog js-review-dialog dno danger-dialog">
    <div class="header">
        <h3>
            Review queues
        </h3>
                <div class="-right">
                    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/review">all queues</a>
                </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-content">
        <ul>
                <li class="-item danger-active">
                    <a href="/review/close" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="review_popup_item.click({ item_type: 2, in_danger: false })">
                        <span class="-title">Close Votes</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="-item danger-active">
                    <a href="/review/reopen" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="review_popup_item.click({ item_type: 6, in_danger: false })">
                        <span class="-title">Reopen Votes</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="-item danger-none">
                    <a href="/review/helper" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="review_popup_item.click({ item_type: 11, in_danger: false })">
                        <span class="-title">Help and Improvement</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="-item danger-none">
                    <a href="/review/low-quality-posts" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="review_popup_item.click({ item_type: 3, in_danger: false })">
                        <span class="-title">Low Quality Posts</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="-item danger-urgent">
                    <a href="/review/suggested-edits" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="review_popup_item.click({ item_type: 1, in_danger: true })">
                        <span class="-title">Suggested Edits</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="-item danger-urgent">
                    <a href="/review/first-posts" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="review_popup_item.click({ item_type: 4, in_danger: true })">
                        <span class="-title">First Posts</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="-item danger-none">
                    <a href="/review/late-answers" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="review_popup_item.click({ item_type: 5, in_danger: false })">
                        <span class="-title">Late Answers</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="-item danger-urgent">
                    <a href="/review/triage" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="review_popup_item.click({ item_type: 10, in_danger: true })">
                        <span class="-title">Triage</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                            <li class="-item danger-none">
                    <a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review">
                        <span class="-title">Meta Reviews »</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
        </ul>
        <script>
            StackExchange.gps.bindTrackClicks(".review-dialog");
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Stack Exchange is returning these values, not the browser interpreting them incorrectly.

Comment: I knew Chrome couldn't be trusted...