# The triage queue is marked in red, for me, for hours, but when I open it it's empty

Tags: bug, review-queues

Since the morning I was checking the review queues but they were empty so I carried on my other work. But while browsing a SO question I've noticed the below change.

[image: Triage with a red dot next to it]

So, I clicked on **Triage** and after the redirection, I got this

[image: 0 Questions in Triage queue]

And still, the **Triage** shows the red dot since this morning, however, all queues are showing **0**

[image: Review queue list screen showing zero]

Is something wrong with my account or is it a bug of SO?

**Edit**
I was banned after 2 hrs since this question! So I don't think the marked duplicate resolves this query. I wasn't banned when I noticed this bug. 
As described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326277/review-queues-arent-being-populated) **it was a database glitch which is not rare!**

**Update**:
Today, it happened again! :(
will it ever get resolved?
[image]

Comment: @tripleee thanks for your support now all the queues have posts to review

Comment: see also: [Review queues aren't being populated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326277/165773) at MSE

Comment: There are three kinds of lies: lies, damned lies, and review queue indicator icons.

Comment: I can confirm that I also experienced this issue a few hours ago; I certainly was not and am not review banned. There was some [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45826941#45826941) amongst some of us who were able to repro this issue.

Comment: I had same issue , I thought [cache was to be blamed](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) .

Comment: Well some manner of bug seems to have been floating around for over 1 year, this is very similar. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356697/top-bar-review-needed-red-dot-showing-but-no-red-dot-in-review-queues. I got the perfect explanation by Bill the Lizard: "The developers are toying with us, luring us into the queue with the red dot, then turning the laser pointer off. ಠ_ಠ"

Comment: Wait, the red dot for Triage isn't a reminder to devs to fix the Requires Editing button?

Comment: I also had this issue about a week ago.

Comment: I've solved the icon problem by placing a circular piece of red tape over the review icon on my screen, works well.

Comment: Leave it be and it will be okay soon.

Comment: Is this an out-of-season April fool's joke?

Comment: Why should Stack Overflow the company care about fixing longstanding bugs when they can add unicorns for one day?

Comment: Fake Queues!  (sorry, couldn't help myself...)

Comment: Q: Why is this question marked as "off-topic"?